# When making desktop applications that use oauth, do I need to store the access token, or can I just store the refresh token?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, desktop-application

So I'm making a desktop app using tauri and rust, and I'm just wondering what the best practice would be for saving tokens for google oauth. What I'm doing at the moment is attempting to just save the oauth refresh token and get a new access token every time the app is opened. I'm just doing this because it will make my implementation much simpler.

And there any downsides to doing this? I still don't know if it works because I haven't quite implemented it.

Comment: your doing exactly what you should 

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some downsides to the solution you describe. One thing is that you have to store the token somewhere on the desktop computer. This might render the token vulnerable to attacks unless you can keep it encrypted or stored in a secure enclave. Also, a desktop client is a public client, so anyone will be able to get tokens based on the refresh token if they manage to get hold of it.

In my opinion, it is better to let the user get a new token from Google every time they open the app. It doesn't add too much hustle but improves the security of your application.

Comment: Well I'm currently using a crate called keyring which provides high level functionality to securely save things like login tokens using native os credential store apis. Now I am basically 99% sure that my implementation is safe, but I don't know a whole lot about encryption, so I'm not certain.

Comment: Which is another reason not to keep the tokens there — if you're unsure ;)